# Balance transferring transaction - PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in a middle of a project and I need to create a page in which the user account will be able to transfer a certain amount of "money" to another registered account.
After the transfer action ends, I need to have a transcript of the transaction.
I created a new DB that contains all the transactions but I can't figure out how to call the data.

I tried to use this in the api.php:

`//get all transactions
case "get_all_transactions":

```
            $cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM transactions");
            $cursor->execute();
            $retval = "";
            
            foreach($cursor->fetchAll() as $row){
                if ($row["send_account"] == $user OR $row["recive_account"] == $user){
                    $retval = retval . "<br>"echo .$row['send_account']."<br>".$row['recive_account']."<br>".$row['amount'];
                }else{
                    $msg = "nope";
                }
            }
            
            echo '{"success":"true","data":"'.$retval.'"}';
            die();
            
            break;`
```

I add this in the transaction.php page:

```
    //get all transactions
    $.post("api.php",{"action":"get_all_transactions"},function(data){
        if(data.success == "true"){
            $("#transactions_history").html(data.data);
        }
    });
```

I can't figure out how to continue.

Can anyone assist, please?

If you have any other way, it will be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Running `"SELECT * FROM transactions"` is like "load the history of the universe" and should be considered a *bad idea*. You should almost always scope with `WHERE`.

Comment: Important things not shown: The relevant schema (via `SHOW CREATE TABLE`) and what constitutes a "balance".

Comment: Tip: Normally these are represented as a ledger where a user's account has credits and debits applied to it, so querying is really quite easy. You effect a transfer with a pair of entries, one to debit one account, one to credit another.

Comment: You should enable errors on your development server so you can be told about mistakes like undefined constant `retval` which would also be pointed out by a good IDE. Also, do not think that you can make your own JSON. You cannot, and that is why PHP has built-in functions to do so. If you chose to look at your browser's JS console you would also be seeing error messages that would hopefully point you to these same problems.

Comment: Also you're parsing your array in whatever order it happens to be returned from the db. Normally, you'd want an ORDER BY clause, or to sort the array prior to parsing.